# Can an email address be added to "Forward To" list in cPanel without accessing the cPanel?

Tags: passwords, email, cpanel

My company is using cPanel emails, recently while reviewing email forwarders, I noticed an email in the "Forward To" list that our sales email is being forwarded to it and that was unknow to me before, knowing that only me have access to our cPanel and there was many ex-employees who had access to our sales email before, my question is:
Is there any way to add an email address to the "forward to" email address list in cPanel without accessing the cPanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved, anyone who has the login credentials to our sales email can access the webmail interface and add forwarders only for the sales email ... thanks you so much..